# Non-linear least squares covariance estimate

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance, nonlinear-regression

In many places I've seen this formula quoted as an estimate for the covariance matrix $C$ in a nonlinear least squares fit: $$C=\sigma^2H^{-1}$$
where $H$ is the Hessian matrix and $\sigma$ is estimated using $\sigma^2=\frac{\boldsymbol{r}^\top\boldsymbol{r}}{m-n}$ where $\boldsymbol{r}$ are the residuals, $n$ is the number of parameters, and $m$ is the number of outputs.

However, I cannot find an explanation of where this formula comes from, particularly the $\sigma$ and its corresponding estimate. Is there any simple explanation for it, or at least a source for one?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fisher+information+variance.  One of the top-voted hits at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10578 looks like a good resource.

Comment: A derivation is given e.g. in sec. 3.1.1 of _Nelles, Oliver. Nonlinear system identification. Springer Nature, 2020._